# Can't extract a particular row from a table using requests module

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

In my current attempt, I can scrape the row from the table starting with `Total Revenue` from this [webpage](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL). If you reload the page, you can see that the content is connected to `Annual` button, which is selected by default. However, what I wish to do is scrape the same row when `Quarterly` button is selected. This [image](https://imagebin.ca/v/76ZtRR5bOfsZ) might clarify things a little better.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

def get_annual_info(link):
    res = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    total_revenue = soup.select_one("[data-test='fin-row']:has(> div > div > div > [aria-label='Total Revenue'])").get_text(strip=True, separator = " ")
    return total_revenue


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_annual_info(link))
```

Current output:

```
Total Revenue 394,328,000 394,328,000 365,817,000 274,515,000 260,174,000
```

Expected output:

```
Total Revenue 394,328,000 90,146,000 82,959,000 97,278,000 123,945,000 83,360,000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded via Javascript so you can use `selenium` or using their API endpoint:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0"
}

api_url = "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/ws/fundamentals-timeseries/v1/finance/timeseries/AAPL"

q = {
    "lang": "en-US",
    "region": "US",
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "padTimeSeries": "true",
    "type": "quarterlyTotalRevenue",
    # "type": "quarterlyTaxEffectOfUnusualItems,trailingTaxEffectOfUnusualItems,quarterlyTaxRateForCalcs,trailingTaxRateForCalcs,quarterlyNormalizedEBITDA,trailingNormalizedEBITDA,quarterlyNormalizedDilutedEPS,trailingNormalizedDilutedEPS,quarterlyNormalizedBasicEPS,trailingNormalizedBasicEPS,quarterlyTotalUnusualItems,trailingTotalUnusualItems,quarterlyTotalUnusualItemsExcludingGoodwill,trailingTotalUnusualItemsExcludingGoodwill,quarterlyNetIncomeFromContinuingOperationNetMinorityInterest,trailingNetIncomeFromContinuingOperationNetMinorityInterest,quarterlyReconciledDepreciation,trailingReconciledDepreciation,quarterlyReconciledCostOfRevenue,trailingReconciledCostOfRevenue,quarterlyEBITDA,trailingEBITDA,quarterlyEBIT,trailingEBIT,quarterlyNetInterestIncome,trailingNetInterestIncome,quarterlyInterestExpense,trailingInterestExpense,quarterlyInterestIncome,trailingInterestIncome,quarterlyContinuingAndDiscontinuedDilutedEPS,trailingContinuingAndDiscontinuedDilutedEPS,quarterlyContinuingAndDiscontinuedBasicEPS,trailingContinuingAndDiscontinuedBasicEPS,quarterlyNormalizedIncome,trailingNormalizedIncome,quarterlyNetIncomeFromContinuingAndDiscontinuedOperation,trailingNetIncomeFromContinuingAndDiscontinuedOperation,quarterlyTotalExpenses,trailingTotalExpenses,quarterlyRentExpenseSupplemental,trailingRentExpenseSupplemental,quarterlyReportedNormalizedDilutedEPS,trailingReportedNormalizedDilutedEPS,quarterlyReportedNormalizedBasicEPS,trailingReportedNormalizedBasicEPS,quarterlyTotalOperatingIncomeAsReported,trailingTotalOperatingIncomeAsReported,quarterlyDividendPerShare,trailingDividendPerShare,quarterlyDilutedAverageShares,trailingDilutedAverageShares,quarterlyBasicAverageShares,trailingBasicAverageShares,quarterlyDilutedEPS,trailingDilutedEPS,quarterlyDilutedEPSOtherGainsLosses,trailingDilutedEPSOtherGainsLosses,quarterlyTaxLossCarryforwardDilutedEPS,trailingTaxLossCarryforwardDilutedEPS,quarterlyDilutedAccountingChange,trailingDilutedAccountingChange,quarterlyDilutedExtraordinary,trailingDilutedExtraordinary,quarterlyDilutedDiscontinuousOperations,trailingDilutedDiscontinuousOperations,quarterlyDilutedContinuousOperations,trailingDilutedContinuousOperations,quarterlyBasicEPS,trailingBasicEPS,quarterlyBasicEPSOtherGainsLosses,trailingBasicEPSOtherGainsLosses,quarterlyTaxLossCarryforwardBasicEPS,trailingTaxLossCarryforwardBasicEPS,quarterlyBasicAccountingChange,trailingBasicAccountingChange,quarterlyBasicExtraordinary,trailingBasicExtraordinary,quarterlyBasicDiscontinuousOperations,trailingBasicDiscontinuousOperations,quarterlyBasicContinuousOperations,trailingBasicContinuousOperations,quarterlyDilutedNIAvailtoComStockholders,trailingDilutedNIAvailtoComStockholders,quarterlyAverageDilutionEarnings,trailingAverageDilutionEarnings,quarterlyNetIncomeCommonStockholders,trailingNetIncomeCommonStockholders,quarterlyOtherunderPreferredStockDividend,trailingOtherunderPreferredStockDividend,quarterlyPreferredStockDividends,trailingPreferredStockDividends,quarterlyNetIncome,trailingNetIncome,quarterlyMinorityInterests,trailingMinorityInterests,quarterlyNetIncomeIncludingNoncontrollingInterests,trailingNetIncomeIncludingNoncontrollingInterests,quarterlyNetIncomeFromTaxLossCarryforward,trailingNetIncomeFromTaxLossCarryforward,quarterlyNetIncomeExtraordinary,trailingNetIncomeExtraordinary,quarterlyNetIncomeDiscontinuousOperations,trailingNetIncomeDiscontinuousOperations,quarterlyNetIncomeContinuousOperations,trailingNetIncomeContinuousOperations,quarterlyEarningsFromEquityInterestNetOfTax,trailingEarningsFromEquityInterestNetOfTax,quarterlyTaxProvision,trailingTaxProvision,quarterlyPretaxIncome,trailingPretaxIncome,quarterlyOtherIncomeExpense,trailingOtherIncomeExpense,quarterlyOtherNonOperatingIncomeExpenses,trailingOtherNonOperatingIncomeExpenses,quarterlySpecialIncomeCharges,trailingSpecialIncomeCharges,quarterlyGainOnSaleOfPPE,trailingGainOnSaleOfPPE,quarterlyGainOnSaleOfBusiness,trailingGainOnSaleOfBusiness,quarterlyOtherSpecialCharges,trailingOtherSpecialCharges,quarterlyWriteOff,trailingWriteOff,quarterlyImpairmentOfCapitalAssets,trailingImpairmentOfCapitalAssets,quarterlyRestructuringAndMergernAcquisition,trailingRestructuringAndMergernAcquisition,quarterlySecuritiesAmortization,trailingSecuritiesAmortization,quarterlyEarningsFromEquityInterest,trailingEarningsFromEquityInterest,quarterlyGainOnSaleOfSecurity,trailingGainOnSaleOfSecurity,quarterlyNetNonOperatingInterestIncomeExpense,trailingNetNonOperatingInterestIncomeExpense,quarterlyTotalOtherFinanceCost,trailingTotalOtherFinanceCost,quarterlyInterestExpenseNonOperating,trailingInterestExpenseNonOperating,quarterlyInterestIncomeNonOperating,trailingInterestIncomeNonOperating,quarterlyOperatingIncome,trailingOperatingIncome,quarterlyOperatingExpense,trailingOperatingExpense,quarterlyOtherOperatingExpenses,trailingOtherOperatingExpenses,quarterlyOtherTaxes,trailingOtherTaxes,quarterlyProvisionForDoubtfulAccounts,trailingProvisionForDoubtfulAccounts,quarterlyDepreciationAmortizationDepletionIncomeStatement,trailingDepreciationAmortizationDepletionIncomeStatement,quarterlyDepletionIncomeStatement,trailingDepletionIncomeStatement,quarterlyDepreciationAndAmortizationInIncomeStatement,trailingDepreciationAndAmortizationInIncomeStatement,quarterlyAmortization,trailingAmortization,quarterlyAmortizationOfIntangiblesIncomeStatement,trailingAmortizationOfIntangiblesIncomeStatement,quarterlyDepreciationIncomeStatement,trailingDepreciationIncomeStatement,quarterlyResearchAndDevelopment,trailingResearchAndDevelopment,quarterlySellingGeneralAndAdministration,trailingSellingGeneralAndAdministration,quarterlySellingAndMarketingExpense,trailingSellingAndMarketingExpense,quarterlyGeneralAndAdministrativeExpense,trailingGeneralAndAdministrativeExpense,quarterlyOtherGandA,trailingOtherGandA,quarterlyInsuranceAndClaims,trailingInsuranceAndClaims,quarterlyRentAndLandingFees,trailingRentAndLandingFees,quarterlySalariesAndWages,trailingSalariesAndWages,quarterlyGrossProfit,trailingGrossProfit,quarterlyCostOfRevenue,trailingCostOfRevenue,quarterlyTotalRevenue,trailingTotalRevenue,quarterlyExciseTaxes,trailingExciseTaxes,quarterlyOperatingRevenue,trailingOperatingRevenue",
    "merge": "false",
    "period1": "493590046",
    "period2": "1671969077",
    "corsDomain": "finance.yahoo.com",
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=q, headers=headers).json()


df = pd.DataFrame(data["timeseries"]["result"][0]["quarterlyTotalRevenue"])
df["reportedValue"] = df["reportedValue"].str["raw"].astype(str)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   dataId    asOfDate periodType currencyCode   reportedValue
0   20100  2021-09-30         3M          USD   83360000000.0
1   20100  2021-12-31         3M          USD  123945000000.0
2   20100  2022-03-31         3M          USD   97278000000.0
3   20100  2022-06-30         3M          USD   82959000000.0
4   20100  2022-09-30         3M          USD   90146000000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it will be possible to get this information only with request, as you will need interaction with the website to click on the **Quarterly Button**.

You can take a look at Selenium : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium to have some interaction with the website

Comment: A few days ago, I noticed the necessary table within the content, next to "root.App.main" (found within the page source), from which I could extract fields using the JSON library. However, the site seems to have undergone some changes in its structure now.